# Why don't masters play 7...e5 against the Fianchetto Variation of the King's Indian?

Tags: opening, analysis, kings-indian

In the Lichess database, this is the most popular way to play against the Fianchetto Variation of the KID:

```
[FEN ""]
1.d4 Nf6 2.c4 g6 3.g3 Bg7 4.Bg2 O-O 5.Nc3 d6 6.Nf3 Nc6 7.O-O e5
```

But at master level, `7...a6` (the Panno Variation) is by far the most popular move, and playing in traditional KID fashion with `7...e5` scores horrendously for Black. What's the reason for this?

Comment: You may find the answers to this question relevant https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/35352/strategic-plans-for-black-in-fianchetto-variation-of-kid

Comment: They don't cover 7...e5. I'm mainly interested in why 7...e5 seems to be so popular at the amateur level, yet is rarely played by masters / has a high winrate for White in master-level games.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found the "refutation" to this setup:

```
[FEN ""]
1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 g6 3. g3 Bg7 4. Bg2 O-O 5. Nc3 d6 6. Nf3 Nc6 7. O-O e5 8. d5 Ne7 9. e4 Nd7 10. Ne1 f5 11. Nd3 Nf6 12. Bg5 h6 13. Bxf6 Bxf6 14. f4
```

I'm no master, but it seems to me like Black's attack has been completely stopped on the kingside because White has managed to blockade e4/f4, while White still has potential for launching a queenside attack. Nearly all of the master games from this position are either White wins or draws.

On the flipside, I did notice that `8...Nb8` scores much better for Black after `8.d5`, but if White plays `9.c5` after that then the winning chances again seem to favor White.

**edit:** Indeed, the `8...Nb8` line is featured on FM Kamil Plichta's Chessable course: https://www.chessable.com/course/31739/

Comment: For many years the line was considered dubious for Black because of this very variation, but lately 8...Nb8 has been a game changer that revived the whole line and White is really struggling to find any advantage against it.